# How to use Kubernetes OICD-Login WITH OTP but WITHOUT userinterface/browser?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, authentication

I am connecting to Kubernetes Cluster, using **kubectl oidc-login**
( https://github.com/int128/kubelogin/ ) and using *grant-type=password* as there is **no browser available** on the system.
This works fine:

```
kubectl get pods
Type Username: xxxx
Type Password xxxx
```

Configuration looks like that:

```
[...]
            command: kubectl
            args:
              - oidc-login
              - get-token
              - --oidc-issuer-url=https://some-keycloak.com/realms/myrealm
              - --oidc-client-id=some-cluster
              - --oidc-client-secret=my_secret
              - --grant-type=password # THIS is the interesting line
```

However, as soon as I add OTP in keycloak my user/password is rejected. **Is there anyway to add the OTP to the password?** (Tried already OTP+Password)